# NodeJS package management

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

I wanted to run this simple line of code (using Node.js 8.0.0) :

```
time node -e "console.log(require('bcrypt').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" your-password-here
```

to compare bcrypt to bcryptjs on my RaspberryPi running Linux Alpine.

At first it gave me :

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^    
Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at (...)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:432:27)
```

So I tried to install bcrypt with this command :

```
npm install -g --production bcrypt
```

which worked (after a fallback to compile from sources since the linux depencies were not found for my armv7 processor).

BUT when trying the test command again, I had exactly the same error (cannot find module 'bcrypt').

It's only after doing what I think is a "project local" install without the "-g" option (even if I had no project) it finally worked and bcrypt was found when running my test command.

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Could some someone familiar with NodeJS explain me this strange mechanism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globally installed packages are not automatically available everywhere. Installing one like you did is a great idea on a platform where clearly you want to compile as little as possible given how long it takes; however, you still need to link globally-installed packages in your local project:

```
# install globally
npm install -g --production bcrypt


# link locally (you must run this in your project's directory)
npm link bcrypt
```

This will create symlink(s) that will simply make the globally-installed module available in the `node_modules` directory of your local project - a much faster operation than recompiling the module once for every project that requires it.

Make sure, however, to remember to update bcrypt running `npm install -g --production bcrypt` again when a new version you need is released. Running `npm update` in your project won't suffice.

[`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) documentation, well worth a read. Note that the behavior of this command is completely different if run without a package name as its argument.